# Multiple requestWithGraphPath Facebook iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

Maybe a simple question but I can't seem to get it. I want to get the users profile picture but also want search his/her posts. Like this:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture?type=large" andDelegate:self];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home?q=TEST" andDelegate:self];
```

I can get the picute out with the following code:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result{
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:result];
        UIImageView *profilePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [image release];
        profilePicture.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80);
        [self.view addSubview:profilePicture];
        [profilePicture release];

    }
}
```

But I don't know how i can get the search query data out.

Any help would be great! Thnx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`requestWithGraphPath:andDelegate:` returns a pointer to an object of type `FBRequest`. Save it and use it later to differentiate between requests in `request:didLoad:` comparing it against the first parameter passed to this method.

---

For example, you can have two properties to hold the request objects. Although, if you are going to deal with many requests, you can use a container like `NSDictionary` instead.

```
self.pictureRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture?type=large" andDelegate:self];
self.homeRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home?q=TEST" andDelegate:self];
```

And then in `request:didLoad:`:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if (request == self.homeRequest) {
        // ...
    } else if (request == self.pictureRequest) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds logical, how would something like this look like? Thnx